# I keep getting a 'Another program is being installed' error

Tags: windows

I'm trying to install Paint.NET for a YouTube icon making. I'm using the dotPDN mirror for downloading the installer in a .install repository that I extract the installer from.

Every time I try to install I get the 'Error: Another program is being installed, please wait until that installation is complete'.

I've looked on the web and I've been on the Services application on Windows and I can't change the Startup Settings someone on a MS forum recommended. I also cannot use the task manager in the way recommended as I'm running Windows X and the task manager displays processes differently.

There is no 'Windows Installer' process that I can see on the task manager however.

I run AVG Internet Security and that has caused installation problems in the past so I disabled that and my firewall but still nothing.

Is it a problem with the installer or Windows? I'm assuming it's Windows, so how do I fix it?

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you tried restarting the PC?

Comment: Are there any `msiexec.exe` processes running before you start the Paint.NET installer?

Comment: **msiexec /unregister** & **msiexec /regserver** try this

Comment: What operating system are you using?  "Windows" doesn't specify which version...